# Personal website of mine shows a blank page on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2

My personal web shows a blank page in Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache 2.4.7.  I have put the web files in `/var/www/html`.

`phpinfo` and `phpmyadmin` are both working fine. Also, please note that the same personal web runs fine on 12.04.

Any advice on this?

Comment: I think you'll have to give a lot more information.

Comment: First of all it's **/var/www/file.html** so place your php or html files inside that path and restart your server **sudo service apache2 restart**

Comment: My answer the this question might help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/520153/testphp-php-404-not-found/520161#520161

Comment: who is the owner of this file? maybe you have to run `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html` or something like that. Wich index file is in this folder? Is it a .html file with php content? Then you have to rename it to .php

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i suggest. Install apache, php following the commands below in terminal

```
#if you don't have apache and php installed
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5
#create the info.php file either like this or using an editor
sudo echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" >> /var/www/html/info.php 
#restart the apache web server
sudo service apache2 restart
#open a firefox browser to see results.
firefox localhost/info.php
```

Tell me how it goes.