# testphp.php 404 Not Found

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp

I installed LAMP Server. I can access `http://localhost`. I can also run successfully phpmyadmin. But when I go to `http://localhost/testphp.php`, I get a 404 not found. The file is in /var/www/testphp.php. The file reads: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. This information was taken from the guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 the default directory for Apache is `/var/www/html`, not `/var/www/`. See http://askubuntu.com/q/448944/158442

Comment: @muru I don't know why that change was made. It makes no sense.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat made sense to Debian devs: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=730372 (we just inherited the change) I don't really care either way - I usually make a copy of the default conf, disable it and work on the copy.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely your file is not in the correct directory. Apache serves files from a directory referred to as the "Document Root". Your files must be in this directory for Apache to find them.

To check what the Apache is using as the Document Root:

- Open a terminal
- run `less /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` (may need sudo)
- Look for the line the looks like `DocumentRoot /some/path`. Its towards the top
- Make sure your php scripts are in `/some/path`

This is assuming you haven't made any configuration changes to Apache. This can be much more complex if you have multiple virtual hosts, and aliases, and so forth. But for the default Apache configuration this will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

As like [dan08](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520153/testphp-php-404-not-found/520161#520161) said, Apache serves files from the directory termed "Document Root". The default "Document Root" is `/var/www/html`.

So, you have two options now.

1. Either, Put your file into `/var/www/html`.
2. Or, Change "Document Root" with the help of [dan08's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520153/testphp-php-404-not-found/520161#520161). For your case, the DocumentRoot value should be `/var/www`.